# Android capture soft keyboard events failed

Tags: android

I need to capture user input in the EditText to delete characters, but when I set the InputType to textEmailAddress, can not capture the deletion of the characters of the incident, only the Chinese input method and Korean input method can be captured.

XML

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/receiverEdit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:completionThreshold="1"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:maxLength="50"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAppearance="?   
    android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/new_mail_label_text_color" />
```

Java

```
mReceiverEdit.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: your id is ``receiverEdit`` but ``mReceiverEdit`` in java..

Comment: receiverEdit and mReceiverEdit are the same object.